# If $A$ and $B$ are both tautologies, then is it true that $A \iff B$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My reasoning this:
If $B$ is a tautology, then $C \implies B \, \forall \, C: C $ is a proposition.
Thus, $A \implies B$.
If $A$ is a tautology, then $C \implies A \, \forall \, C: C $ is a proposition.
Thus, $B \implies A$.
$\therefore A \iff B$.
***Q.E.D***

Comment: If $A$ is a *tautology* then $A$ is always true (in symbols: $\vDash A$) . Thus, $A$ is [consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) of every $B$, i.e. $B \vDash A$. And the same for $B$.

Answer (score 4):

See [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence):

> two statements $p$ and $q$ are *equivalent* (in symbols: $p \Leftrightarrow q$) if they have the same truth value in every model.

If $A$ and $B$ are *tautologies* they are both true in every model, and thus they have the same truth value in every model.